# User-friendly error pages not displaying in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, appcloud, engineyard

Recently my user friendly error pages stopped displaying for my production environment. I am using rails 3.0.3.

I have the following in my `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

When I start my web server locally using the production environment, the user-friendly error pages display properly.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: The other criteria for showing the errors is request.local? which compares the remote ip address to 127.0.0.1 (and a few others but that's the gist of it). If you're behind a proxy, Rails does something with the action_dispatch.remote_ip environment variable to accomplish the same thing. If you can get a dump of the request environment it might help.

Answer (score 5):

I found a fix for this thanks to Scott at EngineYard

I put this at the beginning of my config/environments/production.rb

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
 def local?
   false
 end
end
```

Comment: great stuff, you saved me some headace :p