# Why is debugging information not showing in my Rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just recently upgraded from Rails 3.0.9 to 3.2.8 and I am seeing user-friendly error pages for my errors instead of the usual error messages.

I've checked the following:

- Ran a `Rails.env` and it showed I was in `development`
- My development.rb has `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

I've searched on google and couldn't find anything else.  Is there anything else I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As said in [User-friendly error pages not displaying in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598983/user-friendly-error-pages-not-displaying-in-production-environment)

> The other criteria for showing the errors is request.local?

So maybe your ip is not showing as a local one to rails (i.e. you are using a proxy). If so or request.local? is not true you could try the patch mentioned in above question (but of course return true and not false ;)